# How to implement a gate that generate a uniform superposition of all permutation of element

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state

I'm looking for a quantum circuit that permits generating a uniform superposition of all possible permutations for example if we have as input $|0123\rangle$ the output will be the uniform superposition of all possible permutation $1/a(|0123\rangle+|1023\rangle+|0213\rangle+.....+|3210\rangle)$. I have already implemented a circuit with SWAP gates but the problem is I'm not getting the uniform superposition.

Comment: seems related to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/11682/55

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the circuit you implemented and the result you get from it.