# How to prepare a quantum circuit for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$ starting from $|00\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction, entanglement

How do I prepare a quantum circuit for  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|00\rangle+|01\rangle+|10\rangle)$ state starting from the $|00\rangle$ state?

I have no clue how to do it. I tried with controlled Hadamard gate but of no use here. Can someone help?
Furthermore, can it be constructed with only one CNOT and any number of single-qubit gates?

Comment: Check this question https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/how-can-i-build-a-circuit-to-generate-an-equal-superposition-of-3-outcomes-for-2/

Answer (score 6):

Step 1: Find the Schmidt decomposition $|\psi\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|u_i\rangle|v_i\rangle$. I won't do this completely here, but
$$
\alpha_0=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{6}},\qquad |u_0\rangle=|v_0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}(2|0\rangle+(\sqrt{5}-1)|1\rangle)
$$
should be enough to confirm you're going in the right direction.

Step 2: Express this as $(U_A\otimes U_B)(\alpha_0|00\rangle+\alpha_1|11\rangle)$.

Step 3: Write down the circuit. First apply $U|0\rangle\rightarrow \alpha_0|0\rangle+\alpha_1|1\rangle$ on the first qubit. Then apply $CNOT$ gate with first qubit as control and second qubit as target. Then apply $U_A\otimes U_B$.