# What is a simple example of "weak entanglement" in a two-qubit system?

Tags: entanglement

Bell states produce maximal entanglement between two qubits. On the other hand, two unentangled qubits provide no (i.e. minimal) entanglement at all.

However, I haven't seen any example of a weak entanglement and how it can be prepared.

Answer (score 6):

The state
$|\psi\rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle}{\sqrt{3}} $ is not separable/untangled since a pure state $|\psi\rangle=a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle+c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle$ is unentangled if and only if $ad - bc = 0$. But it is not a maximal entangled state either as @AdamZalcman pointed out in the comment as the Schmidt decomposition of this state do not have two equal Schmidt coefficient
of $1/\sqrt{2}$. In fact, here the [Schmidt decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_decomposition) of this state $|\psi\rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle}{\sqrt{3}} $  is:

$$|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{6} }|u_1\rangle|v_1\rangle +  \sqrt{\dfrac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{6} }|u_2\rangle|v_2\rangle  $$

where $|u_1 \rangle , |u_2\rangle  $ are the eigenvectors of the reduced density operator $\rho^A = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $ correspond to the eigenvalues $\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{6} $ and $\dfrac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{6}$ respectively.
Similarly, $|v_1 \rangle , |v_2\rangle  $ are the eigenvectors of the reduced density operator $\rho^B = \dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $ correspond to the eigenvalues $\dfrac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{6} $ and $\dfrac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{6}$ respectively. Therefore, it is **not** a maximal entangled state.

---

You can prepare such state using [this circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%7B%22id%22:%22Ryft%22,%22arg%22:%221.232%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22Ryft%22,%22arg%22:%22pi/4%22%7D%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22X%22,%7B%22id%22:%22Ryft%22,%22arg%22:%22-pi/4%22%7D%5D%5D%7D) in **Quirk**, which was also shown in Martin Vesely's answer [here.](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9533/9858)

Comment: +1 This is a nice example of a non-maximally-entangled state and a useful general rule for quickly checking for entanglement. Minor comment: A maximally entangled state of two qubits is one with two equal Schmidt coefficients (both $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$). Therefore, Bell states aren't the only maximally entangled states of two qubits, e.g. $(|00\rangle+i|11\rangle)/\sqrt2$ is also maximally entangled.

Comment: @AdamZalcman Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer to incorporate in your very helpful (as always) comment.

Answer (score 3):

Another standard example are [Werner states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_state). These can be written as
$$W_p\equiv p \frac{I}{4} + (1-p) \frac{|\Psi^-\rangle\!\langle\Psi^-|}{2},\qquad p\in[0,1],$$
and you can tune the entanglement by changing $p$. You can prove that the $W_p$ is entangled for $p<2/3$, and you go from a maximally entangled state at $p=0$ to a totally mixed state at $p=1$.